# How to get the nth subdirectory in Python?

Tags: python, directory, python-os

Suppose I have a file known as xyz in a folder as shown below:

```
Directory
   |
   |+ Subdirectory_n
           |
           |+ Subdirectory_(n-1)
                   |
                   |+ Subdirectory_(n-2)
                           |
                           |+ Subdirectory_(n-3)
                                    ........
                                           |+ Subdirectory_1
                                                   |
                                                   |+ xyz
```

And if I want the nth subdirectory from the file, how do I obtain it python?
For e.g. for the 2nd sub directory I can do something like:

```
import os
file = open('xyz.dat', 'w+')
print os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

for the third

```
import os
file = open('xyz.dat', 'w+')
print os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

This method looks a bit awkward. Is there a better way to do this, so that I can generalize it for an nth subdirectory in Python?

Comment: Do you want the subdirectory or the containing directory?

Comment: @JeremyKemball The nth subdirectory starting 0 from the file.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive approach:

```
def nth_parent(path, n): return path if n <= 0 else os.path.dirname(nth_parent(path, n-1))
```

`n` is the number of levels to go up the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the absolute path of the file using `os.path.abspath()` That should give you something like 'C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\...'. You can then use string operations to find the nth directory.

Answer (score 1):

You know this calls for a clever-clogs recursive solution but perhaps something like

```
n=5
while(n):
    path=os.path.dirname(path)
    n -=1
```

would be clear and preserve the os.path localization magic you would lose by just splitting os.path.abspath().

You could always try something like

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(__file__+"../"*n))
```

but that's not guaranteed to work for all symlinks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit awkward, but short enough to use directly:

`reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), [os.path.dirname]*n, path)`

Answer (score 0):

Python ≥ 3.4 implement [PEP 428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/) and brings you [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), giving you more flexibility.

The "modern" way to do it could be resumed with:

```py
pathlib.Path('xyz.dat').resolve().parents[nth_parent - 1]

# equivalent of:
filename = os.path.realpath('xyz.dat')
for _ in range(nth_parent):
    filename = os.path.dirname(filename)
```

Where `nth_parent` is the [number of ancestors](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/#sequence-like-access) and zero mean the immediate parent (hence the  `- 1` in the example).

Equivalences (with [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)):

```
filename = 'xyz.dat'
pathlib.Path(filename).resolve(), os.path.realpath(filename)

# PurePath does not have resolve() nor other features added by the Path subclass;
# but when the paths are absolutes, those two are similar
pathlib.Path(__file__) == pathlib.PurePath(__file__)

pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[0], pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, os.path.dirname(__file__)

pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1], pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```